# Print the next line from SQLite

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

**My problem:**

In my application I read the address details from a SQLite database & display the result in a textview.

**My sqlite sample address** - 41 South Station Road,'\n' Colchester, '\n' CO1 1RQ

But the next line using '\n' is not working. It prints directly '\n' in the textview.

**My output:**

[image]

**What I have tried**

From [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063567/writing-a-n-in-a-text-file)

41 South Station Road,"\\n" Colchester, "\\n" CO1 1RQ

41 South Station Road,"\n" Colchester, "\n" CO1 1RQ

41 South Station Road,\n Colchester, \n CO1 1RQ

All of the above are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code solve my problem..

```
 string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16287239/3879847

thanks to @Robert